# Using WebService without MVC 5 and 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a WebService which load an assambly MVC 5 from other project, but i don't use MVC or Razor assamblies.

Error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +12980619
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +12980328
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +280
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12979668
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12819261
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How remove this dependence?

Comment: You should post the exception in more readable format. You can format it like code.

Comment: Are you asking about Web API or Web Service ?

Comment: @dotnetstep I can't run my webservice into browser. The project compiled successfull.

Comment: Check your web.config . If you don't use Razor then please remove those reference from all place in project.

Comment: i deleted all dependencies from Web.config and packages.config. If I add reference to MVC4 assembly. Webservice is working.

Comment: But I don't need unused functional represent to MVC assembly